# Redux, state not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

trying to make an option to change the color of text,border,background but i get the error state is not defined in the console.it says that state.options.text that i addressed in option page is not defined,
i checked the routing and it is Ok

option page

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {textCH, borderCh, backgroundCh} from '../Utilities/options/theme'
function Options() {

    const textcolor = useSelector((state)=>state.options.text)

    console.log(textcolor);
    return (
        <div style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }}>
            <h1>OPTIONS</h1>

            text color: <input type={'color'} /> 
            border color: <input type={'color'} /> 
            background color: <input type={'color'} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Options
```

Reducer

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
   text:'#000000',
    border:'#000000',
    background:'#FFFFFF',
}

export const optionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'options',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    textCH: (state,action) => {
         state.text = action.payload
    },
    borderCh: (state,action) => {
      state.border = action.payload
    },
    backgroundCh: (state, action) => {
      state.background = action.payload
    },
  },
})
export const { textCH, borderCh, backgroundCh } = optionsSlice.actions
export default optionsSlice.reducer
```

Store file

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {optionsSlice} from './options/theme'
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    options: optionsSlice,
  },
})
```

Console error:

Uncaught TypeError: state.options is undefined
textcolor Options.jsx:6

Provider setup:

```
     import React from "react";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
        import App from "./App";
        import {store} from "./Utilities/store";
        import { Provider } from "react-redux";
        
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
        root.render(
          <>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <App />
            </Provider>
          </>
        );
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add codesandbox link with the code you have tried? it will be easy for us to debug.

Comment: Can you please show up the `Provider` setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the slice itself in the `store.js`, not reducer.

instead of calling the named function:

```
import {optionsSlice} from './options/theme'
```

we should call the default one:

```
import optionsSlice from './options/theme'
```